# MimeMessageHelper encode text does not encode correctly some strings

Tags: java, encoding, mime-types

I'm having a method where the MimeMessageHelper is used to add attachments to the MimeMessage.

To do that, the following code is used :

```
helper.addAttachment(fileName, new ConstantByteArrayInputStreamSource(doc), contentType);
```

The weird part is that some of the file names are not correctly inserted. For example, the following name "**Action-41080-Cmd_Rappért-20220301_094222.xml**" results in the following file name :
**=UTF-8QAction=5F41080=5FCmd=5FRapp=C3=A9rt=5F20220301=5F=** which is obviously not what I want.

So i thought the accent was the issue but when I run with "**Action_41080_Cmd_Rappért**" it works.

And if I remove the accent (**Action-41080-Cmd_Rapport-20220301_094222.xml**) it works.

The problem comes from the encodeText part in the MimeUtility which appears to have troubles with this particular string.

Thanks for your time,

If anyone has an idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to look elsewhere to find the cause of your troubles. A simple test shows that `MimeUtility.encodeText` works as expected.

```java
import javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility;

// To get required dependency:
// mvn dependency:copy -Dartifact=com.sun.mail:jakarta.mail:1.6.7 -DoutputDirectory=.
public class Q71383383 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        final String fname = "Action-41080-Cmd_Rappért-20220301_094222.xml";
        
        try {
            var encoded = MimeUtility.encodeText(fname);
            // =?UTF-8?Q?Action-41080-Cmd=5FRapp=C3=A9rt-20220301=5F094222.xml?=
            System.out.println(encoded);
            var decoded = MimeUtility.decodeText(encoded);
            System.out.println(decoded);
            System.out.println(fname);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I was really looking in bad direction. Effectively, the encode encodes but its the first string that gets not decoded. When i pass =?UTF-8?Q?Action-41080-Cmd=5FRapp=C3=A9rt.xml?= or  =?UTF-8?Q?Action-41080-Cmd=5FRapp=C3=A9rt?= in attachment name, its ok, but the =?UTF-8?Q?Action-41080-Cmd=5FRapp=C3=A9rt-20220301=5F094222.xml?= does not get decoded although the decode seems to work as expected.